# Debugging Firebreath using gdb in Linux

Tags: c++, plugins, gdb, firebreath

The issue is simple. I have my plugin created by Firebreath and would like to debug my *API.cpp file using `gdb` in Linux.

Yes, i already read [this](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Debugging+Plugins#DebuggingPlugins-Linux) article, and i got this PID:

```
30227  0.0  0.4 115024 12300 pts/2    Sl+  00:03   0:00 /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --type=plugin --plugin-path=/home/USER/Documents/mycode/0.1/npMyPlugin.so
```

When i opened with `gdb` i always get a similar output like this:

```
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libpcrecpp.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libpcrecpp.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libssh2.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libssh2.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

Probably not the right process. Any idea?

Thanks in advanced.

**Update - Ignoring the message**
Thanks guys for your comments. Well i ignored the message and did the following:

```
(gdb) r  
The program being debugged has been started already.  
Start it from the beginning? (y or n)  
Program not restarted.  
(gdb) b 328  
No line 328 in the current file.  
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or n)
```

So basically `gdb` load my MyPlugin.cpp and not my MyPluginAPI.cpp. Any idea?

Comment: Those are just warnings. Doesn't gdb work after that? If so, what actual error is it giving you?

Comment: This only tells you that no debugging symbols could be found for the libraries -- no worries, that is no problem as long as you don't want to debug into library code, which you maybe don't want anyways.

Comment: I already edited the original with the update.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a break point with just a line-number only works if you have exactly one source file.

Use e.g. `b MyPluginAPI.cpp:328` or `b MyPluginAPI::myMethod()` instead.